# Modify the image preview area after upload in Drupal 7

Tags: views, 7, media, files

I am new to Drupal. I wanted to have table less render view of images after upload at editing window. I found lots of help content, but they are hard to understand. Currently i have following view:

[image]

But i need following view with drag-n-drop sorting facility:
[image]

I am using [File Resumable Upload](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup) to upload images. Can anyone tell me what i should do.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please see help center. Image-based questions are listed on the "don't" list. Whilst your question is not exactly image only, it does not show how you have tried to do this, and where you got stuck, so people may perceive it as "do my work for me" question. I guess that's why you got downvotes.

Comment: I got it. I will post the question in right way as you suggested. Thank you very much. @Mołot

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews). For content view displays you have to use a display and a sort block. Pointers can be found [here](http://www.canishe.com/dlu/node/1).

**Edited 'here' link**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the module 'views' that you tagged in your question won't be interacting at the edit stage unless you have something else in play that you haven't mentioned.

This sounds like a primarily CSS question... since you need the display altered at the edit stage, you should be able to tinker with the css to change the effected classes and id's to suit your display needs.

Also, if you don't intend to use the alternate text, you should be able to remove that directly from the field management screen.